# How to fix 'You are using an incompatible schema.xml configuration file' error in drupal for solCloud configuration

Tags: linux, drupal, solr, solrcloud

I am setting up SolrCloud configuration for already existed solr configuration with drupal-7. I have configured zookeeper in 3 different machines and SolrCloud in 2 other machines. All the conf files are present in the configs directory in zookeeper.
Everything is fine till here but communication between drupal and Solr in not happening due to the following error. 
Error: "You are using an incompatible schema.xml configuration file. Please follow the instructions in the handbook for setting up Solr."

Currently, Application is running on drupal-7 and solr-7.x-1.13 module is installed.

Till now, I didn't touch any solr configuration files in drupal server.
What else configuration I have to modify here to resolve the schema.xml incompatibility error?

I tried by configuring solrCloud using 5.4.1 and 6.4.1 version but I am getting same error.

Comment: check https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr/issues/2845504

Comment: Thanks Nic but It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, what fixed this issue was killing the solr process and then starting solr again.

First, find the relevant solr process by trying to start solr...

```
cd /base/path/for/your/solr
bin/solr start
```

You will see something like...

```
Port 8983 is already being used by another process (pid: 12345)
```

Kill whatever process ID is mentioned in the "already being used" message...

```
kill 12345
```

Now you should be able to start solr...

```
bin/solr start
```

After this restart of solr, I refreshed the page in Drupal and the "incompatible schema.xml" message was gone.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to look at the solr error logs to see what part of your schema.xml is not right.
You'd really have to do this is each one of your solr cloud nodes, since there isn't any guarantee that zookeeper uploaded the correct schema.xml on all shards, and that's why you could be getting that error.
You could use zkcli to upload your configs (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/command-line-utilities.html), and then reload your collection on all nodes to apply the changes, but even then there's no guarantee it'll work.

To save time and stress, you could just use a SaaS service, such as https://opensolr.com
You can get it setup for free and you get a UI to edit your config files, upload your config files to your server, and a lot of other nice UI features to manage your solr index.